# Camunda set Execution Variable

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying to set a process variable in Task Listener of a human-task using Groovy script during 'create' as event type in Camunda BPMN work-flow.

execution.setVariable('newUserType',"RMAOFF1");

But it is giving me error saying "The task does not exist or the corresponding process instance could not be resumed successfully."

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In a Task Listener you don't have an execution (DelegateExecution).

But you have a task (DelegateTask delegateTask).

So your example is: `task.setVariable('newUserType',"RMAOFF1")`

By the way this would also work in an expression `${task.setVariable('newUserType',"RMAOFF1")}`

For more infos see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/process-applications/process-application-event-listeners/

Answer (score 0):

The signature of a TaskListener is `void notify(DelegateTask task)`. I guess you are accidentally using an ExceutionListener, but that does not have a "create" event.

Comment: No Jan, I'm trying to code in the BPM modeller itself. I'm aware if Task and Execution Listeners and currently have gone through the same approach since I was not able to set it in the BPM modeller.